bars overlap when width and dodge are used
df <- data.frame(y = c(3,5,9,10,3,2,5,5), x = c("A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B"), g = c("G1","G2","G1","G2","G1","G2","G1","G2"), f = c("F1","F1","F1","F1","F2","F2","F2","F2"))

I'd like to dodge the bars with width=2, so I did:
p < ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=g), data=df)
p + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", width=2) + facet_grid(.~f)

But the bars are overlapping and I'm getting the warning messages:
Warning messages:
1: `position_dodge()` requires non-overlapping x intervals 
2: `position_dodge()` requires non-overlapping x intervals


The width=2 is causing the error; if you change it to '0.2' there's no error. Do you get your desired effect with position = position_dodge(width = 2) in place of position="dodge", width=2?

@jared_mamrot, thanks for your comment. The point of using width=2 was to make the bars thicker while keeping them dodged. Changing the width to 0.2 not only increases the distance between bars but also makes the bars thinner. position = position_dodge(width = 2) seems to break the dodging

Oh, I think I understand; what about geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", width=0.9) + or geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", width=0.95) +? The bars are thicker but still dodged; is that what you're looking for? Or have I misunderstood?
